# How to detect OS with wix 3.8

Tags: wix, installation

I'm adding some launching condition to my wix installer. These are contained in a separate file and contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <Property Id="LaunchConditions" Value="1"/>   
      <PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
      <Condition Message="You must install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 in order to use [ProductName].">
        <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
      </Condition>

     <!--If it is a server, it must be windows server 2003 or higher-->
     <Condition Message="[ProductName] requires Windows Server 2003 or higher.">
       <![CDATA[Installed OR (MsiNTProductType > 1 AND VersionNT >= 502)]]>
     </Condition>

     <!--If it is a workstation, it must be windows vista or higher-->
     <Condition Message="[ProductName] requires Windows Vista or higher.">
       <![CDATA[Installed OR (MsiNTProductType = 1 AND VersionNT >= 600)]]>
     </Condition>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

But every time I run my setup on a windows 7 (ultimate) x64 machine it keeps failing the condition for the server and displays that I need to windows 2003 or higher when it should be skipped as MsiNTProductType is 1.

```
Property(C): MsiNTProductType = 1
```

I'm going through a book as I'm writing this and while they don't have the exact same sample, it's very similar and I believe this should work but it doesn't.

Any ideas? Can you spot anything wrong?

Thanks.

Thierry

Answer (score 1):

As I wanted to keep my individual message for each condition depending on whether I was dealing with a workstation or server, I ended up doing the following:

1. Whenever I want to check a workstation condition, return true if it is a server
2. Whenever I want to check a server condition, return true if it is a workstation

So my final code looks like this:

```
<!--
Server check condition:
If workstation, always return true.
If server, check that it is 2003 or higher.
-->
<Condition Message="[ProductName] requires Windows Server 2003 or higher.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR MsiNTProductType = 1 OR (MsiNTProductType > 1 AND VersionNT > 502)]]>
</Condition>

<!--
Client check condition:
If server, always return true.
If workstation, check that it is Vista or higher.
-->
<Condition Message="[ProductName] requires Windows Vista or higher.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR MsiNTProductType > 1 OR (MsiNTProductType = 1 AND VersionNT >= 600)]]>
</Condition>
```

That's it. Thanks @PhilDW and @DaveAndersen for clarifying the "condition" requirement issue!

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has a product type of 1, so that middle test is failing. Remember that launch conditions need to evaluate to true for the install to go ahead, but that middle condition says it needs to be a server 2003 to install, that's the wrong way round.

P.S. Perhaps you should list the exact OS types it should install on because the fact that you get an error on Windows 7 doesn't really describe your requirements.

Comment: I understand what you mean! This is what was bugging me yesterday as when I was reading this condition, I felt I needed to reserve my logic in order to return true. In regards to my requirement, I want to allow the setup to install our client app (rather then server app) on either workstations that are windows vista or higher but I also want to let the user install it on a server if required but the server has to be 2003 or higher.

Comment: As PhilDW said, your install conditions need to be true (all of them). You should merge the last two conditions into a single condition using an `OR`.